# TYPO3 TCA select list in backend user language

Tags: typo3, backend, typo3-7.6.x

I build an extension that can assign a tag to an object, this is a 1:n relation to the object and the tag gets selected from a list that a simple editor cannot edit.

the admin has to supply the tags and the translations for every tag, so I was able to limit the list to the items in the default language with this TCA:

```
    'tag' => [
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => 'tag',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
            'items' => [
                ['none' , 0]
            ],
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_myextension_domain_model_tags',
            'foreign_table_where' => ' AND tx_myextension_domain_model_tags.sys_language_uid IN (-1, 0)',
            'MM' => 'tx_myextension_object_tags_mm',
            'maxitems' => 1,
            'multiple' => 0,
            'default' => 0,
        ],

    ],
```

but rather than the default language `IN (-1, 0)` i'd like to display the list in the selected language for the backend user `= ###BE_user_language_uid###`... is this possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `###REC_FIELD_sys_language_uid###` to access the `sys_language_uid` field of the current record.

However it is not possible to use the language of the backend user, because frontend translation has nothing to do with backend localization.

Comment: Thanx for that info, one question; if my default language would be italian how would I do that in `Resources/Private/Language` ... now I use `it.locallang.xlf` but that should be `en.locallang.xlf` since English would be an additional language

Comment: English is always the default language regarding translation files. However you can configure any language your want. Have a look into the translation guide.